# C# ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, can not figure it out

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, outofrangeexception

I am getting ArgumentOutOfRange Exception (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.) in my app that deals with graphics (but I guess that it is not that important to figure out where the error is).

Here is my method:

```
  public void InverznaFunkcia2(double a, double b, int n, List<Point> F, int m)
    {
        int i = 0;
        double yj = F[0].Y;
        double KrokX = (b - a) / n;
        double KrokY = (F[0].Y - F[n].Y) / m;


        for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
        {
            while (yj > F[i + 1].Y)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                if (F[i].Y > 200)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            invF.Add(j);

            //EXCEPTION THROWN ON THE FOLLOWING LINE:
            invF[j] =( a + (j + ((yj - F[i].Y) / (F[i + 1].Y - F[i].Y)) * KrokX));
           // invF[j].X = a + (j + ((yj - F[i].Y) / (F[i + 1].Y - F[i].Y)) * KrokX);
            yj = yj + KrokY;
            pomocneX.Add(j);
            double ux =  F[i].X -F[i+1].X;
            double uy =  F[i].Y - F[i+1].Y;
            double t = (invF[j] - F[i].Y) / uy;
            pomocneX[j] = F[i].X + (t * ux);



            //pomocneX[j] = ( a +  (j + ((yj - F[i].X) / (F[i + 1].X - F[i].X)) * KrokX));
            textBox3.Text += "invF" + j + "\t" + (invF[j] + "\r\n");
            textBox4.Text += "X" + j + "\t" + (pomocneX[j] + "\r\n"); 
        }
        //invF.Add(m);
       // invF[m] = (double)b;

    }
```

I know that this type of exception has been discussed here, but I have no idea how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why do not you simply add a break point and validate the size of invF and F in comparison with i and j !

Comment: the IDE doesn't *always* get it right, but you could *also* just try hitting Start ([F5]), and see if the IDE blows up and catches the exception at the right time, with the current values...

Comment: in your first while loop you increment i and check that F[i] exists, but in your erroring line you check F[i+1]. so when i happens to be the last element of F your code errors

Answer (score 2):

k; so let's dissect:

```
//EXCEPTION THROWN ON THE FOLLOWING LINE:
invF[j] =( a + (j + ((yj - F[i].Y) / (F[i + 1].Y - F[i].Y)) * KrokX));
```

Now; I *could* start asking things like "`j` is bounded by `m`; how do we know if  `invF[j]` makes sense?"; however, it would be easier to just add some debug code:

```
try {
    invF[j] =( a + (j + ((yj - F[i].Y) / (F[i + 1].Y - F[i].Y)) * KrokX));
} catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
    Console.WriteLine("i={0},j={1},|invF|={2},|F|={3}",
        i, j, invF.Length, F.Length);
    throw;
}
```

That should show you where the problem is.

Comment: Of course, a breakpoint or 2 would make this even easier for the op :)

Comment: @Sayse well, a breakpoint on the *original* line might not help if it fails on the 4231st iteration - but a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine`: sure

Comment: Sure, but then theres conditionals or [when an exception is thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx). (Note: this is more a note for the OP)

Comment: @MarcGravell System.Collection.Generic.List<double> does not contain a definition for 'Length' ... How can I go around this?

Comment: @user2179427 by using `.Count` instead